# less gives a bunch of files opened

Tags: linux, less, man

I tried to open a file using less:

```
less /home/me/Desktop/file1
```

This is returning unexpected result like this:

```
/usr/bin/less: 1: [: missing ]
At least one file or directory argument required.
Use --help to show usage.

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,3 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz (40651),ASM,AES-NI)

Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
       [<@listfiles...>]

<Commands>
  a : Add files to archive
  b : Benchmark....
.
.
.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Ynm.png)
It says /usr/bin/less: 1: [:missing]
At least one file or directory argument required.

I'm a linux beginner, i started to learn the basic and mess around with the system files for few days. Perhaps i broke something, and when i wanted to see a file using less, it gives me a bunch of man pages, and it didn't stop.

How can i figure out where or what is wrong and fix it?

Opening a command manual page using man also gives me same result:

```
man ls
```

This is returning same result as using less but followed by some informative errors and also it took like so long to finish, and i think it never stop giving a bunch of errors until i pressed crtl+c :

```
Too many errors from stdinant to give up? 
/usr/bin/bashbug: editor `editor' exited with nonzero status.
/usr/bin/bashbug: Perhaps it was interrupted.
/usr/bin/bashbug: Type `y' to give up, and lose your bug report;
/usr/bin/bashbug: type `n' to re-enter the editor.
Too many errors from stdinant to give up? 
/usr/bin/bashbug: editor `editor' exited with nonzero status.
/usr/bin/bashbug: Perhaps it was interrupted.
/usr/bin/bashbug: Type `y' to give up, and lose your bug report;
/usr/bin/bashbug: type `n' to re-enter the editor.
Too many errors from stdinant to give up? 
/usr/bin/bashbug: editor `editor' exited with nonzero status.
/usr/bin/bashbug: Perhaps it was interrupted.
/usr/bin/bashbug: Type `y' to give up, and lose your bug report;
/usr/bin/bashbug: type `n' to re-enter the editor.
```

Comment: Post the exact command you enter, else nobody can give a useful answer.

Comment: less /home/me/Desktop/file1    This is the command i used. Thanks for the advise @AdrianZaugg

Comment: Depends on what you was playing with. Start with "ls -la /usr/bin/less" and "file /usr/bin/less".